# PHP: autoloading multiple classes with namespaces

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, namespaces, autoload

I'm trying to build my own framework for internal usage.
I got structure like this:

```
index.php
boot /
    booter.php
application /
     controllers /
           indexcontroller.php
core /
    template.class.php
    model.class.php
    controller.class.php
    cache / 
         memcached.php
    something /
         something.php
```

Booter.php contains: (it's currently working only with files located in core directory):

```
class Booter
{
private static $controller_path, $model_path, $class_path;

public static function setDirs($controller_path = 'application/controllers', $model_path = 'application/models', $classes_path = 'core')
{
    self::$controller_path = $controller_path;
    self::$model_path      = $model_path;
    self::$class_path      = $classes_path;

    spl_autoload_register(array('Booter', 'LoadClass'));
    if ( DEBUG ) 
        Debugger::log('Setting dirs...');
}

protected static function LoadClass($className) 
{
    $className = strtolower($className);

    if ( file_exists(DIR . '/' . self::$model_path . '/' . $className . '.php') ) 
    {
        require(DIR . '/' . self::$model_path . '/' . $className . '.php');
    }       
    else if ( file_exists(DIR . '/' . self::$class_path . '/' . $className . '.class.php') ) 
    {
        require(DIR . '/' . self::$class_path . '/' . $className . '.class.php');
    }
    else if ( file_exists(DIR . '/' . self::$controller_path . '/' . $className . '.php') )
    {
        require(DIR . '/' . self::$controller_path . '/' . $className . '.php');
    }

    if ( DEBUG )
        Debugger::log('AutoLoading classname: '.$className);
}
}
```

My application/controllers/indexcontroller looks like this:

```
<?
class IndexController extends Controller
{
     public function ActionIndex()
     {
          $a = new Model; // It works
          $a = new Controller; //It works too
     }
}

?>
```

And here comes my questions:

**[Question 1]**

My code is working currently like this:

```
$a = new Model; // Class Model gets included from core/model.class.php
```

How I can implement including files by classes with namespaces? For example:

```
$a = new Cache\Memcached; // I would like to include file from /core/CACHE/Memcached.php
$a = new AnotherNS\smth; // i would like to include file from /core/AnotherNS/smth.php
```

and so on. How I can produce the handling of the namespace?

**[Question 2]**

Is it a good practice to use single autoload for Classes, Controllers and models or I should define 3 different spl_autoload_register with 3 different methods and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

In your autoloader, change the \ (for the namespace) into `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. This should work:

```
protected static function LoadClass($className) 
{
    $className = strtolower($className);
    $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
...
}
```

Always use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, especially if the software has the potential to be used on other platforms.

Question 2:

I would use one and separate your classes by namespace. However, I think that comes down to how you want to structure your framework and how you separate your code. Someone else may be able to better answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

I normally have a `bootstrap.php` file inside a folder `conf` that is in the application root. My code is normally located inside an `src` folder, also located in the root, so, this works fine for me:

```
<?php

define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array_unique(
            array_merge(
                array(
                    APP_ROOT . 'src', 
                    APP_ROOT . 'test'
                ),
                explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path())
            )
        )
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $file = sprintf("%s.php", str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class));
    if (($classPath = stream_resolve_include_path($file)) != false) {
        require $classPath;
    }
}, true);
```

You can generalize this into your "Booter" class and append directories to the include path. If you have well defined namespace names, there will be no problems with colisions.

**Edit:**
This works if you follow [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md).